# Including Zend Framework library in php.ini on bluehost server

Tags: zend-framework, deployment, bluehost

I'm not able to set up include paths for ZF library correctly on Bluehost server.

Here's the directory structure:

```
/root_directory

 .htaccess

 __/Zend

 __Application(from ZF)

 __library(from ZF)

 __/public_html

    __/public(the ZF public folder)
```

I removed the .htaccess from public folder and placed it in the root_directory.

contents of .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^.htaccess$ - [F]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =""
RewriteRule ^.*$ /public/index.php [NC,L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/.$
RewriteRule ^(.)$ /public/$1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
```

RewriteRule ^public/.*$ /public/index.php [NC,L]

Contents of index.php in public folder:

```
// Define path to application directory
defined('APPLICATION_PATH')
    || define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../application'));

// Define application environment
defined('APPLICATION_ENV')
    || define('APPLICATION_ENV', (getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ?  getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') : 'production'));

// Ensure library/ is on include_path
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library'),
    get_include_path(),
)));

/** Zend_Application */
require_once 'Zend/Application.php';

// Create application, bootstrap, and run
$application = new Zend_Application(
    APPLICATION_ENV,
    APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini'
);
$FrontController = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
$Router=$FrontController->getRouter();

  Zend_Layout::startMvc(array(
    "layout" => "layout",
    "layoutPath" => "layouts/scripts"
    ));

$plugin=new Zend_Controller_Plugin_ErrorHandler();
$plugin->setErrorHandler(array("controller" =>'ApplicationError',
                               "action"=>'index'));
$FrontController->registerPlugin($plugin);

$application->bootstrap()
            ->run();
```

Kindly help me deploying my project on server. If there is anything else I need to mention please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if doing the following gets you up and running:

- Move contents of `public_html/public` into `public_html` and delete the `public` folder
- Delete `root_directory/.htaccess`
- Create `public_html/.htaccess`

In `public_html/.htaccess`, put:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

- Your `index.php` file looks fine, no need to change `APPLICATION_PATH`.

Basically, the only change is that instead of actually using the `public` folder that came with Zend Framework, you replace it with `public_html` instead since that is really your public folder.

Comment: Though I did work out a way to make it work a little, I gave your solution a try. It is rendering layout but couldn't find the view script. I get the following error when I access the home directory: script ''home'/index.phtml' not found in path (/home1/wethemen/application/views/scripts/)

Comment: Don't know everything that works on localhost seems to break on server. Even a simple thing like: $this->url('controller'=>'home', 'action'=>'contact-us'),null,true) isn't working.

Comment: Do you have a file `/home1/wethemen/application/views/scripts/home/index.phtml`?  That is a view script that ZF is trying to render.  That exception is normal if it can't find view script.